# Mongo errors when mongoose is updated from 3.8.8 to 4.x

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack, meanjs

I have a MEAN stack project.
I'm using node v5.9.1 with

```
"mongoose": "~3.8.8"
```

MongoDB shell version: 3.0.10 on Ubuntu 15.10

I need to use `mongoose-encryption` which says it needs mongoose 4.x.

Whenever i upgrade mongoose from 3.8 to 4.x, the server keeps crashing when a request is received.

```
info: MEAN.JS application started on port 3000

(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 reconnect listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at addListener (events.js:252:17)
    at Server.connect (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:326:17)
    at open (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:224:19)
    at Db.open (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:247:44)
    at MongoStore._open_database (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:182:15)
    at MongoStore._get_collection (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:177:14)
    at /media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/connect-mongo/lib/connect-mongo.js:194:16
    at /media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:234:5
    at connectHandler (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:306:7)
    at g (events.js:273:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at emit (events.js:182:7)
    at /media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:540:23
    at commandCallback (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1161:9)
    at Callbacks.emit (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:119:3)
    at null.messageHandler (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:295:23)
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 destroy listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at addListener (events.js:252:17)
    at once (events.js:278:8)
    at connectHandler (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:281:19)
    at g (events.js:273:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at emit (events.js:182:7)
    at /media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:540:23
    at commandCallback (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1161:9)
    at Callbacks.emit (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:119:3)
    at null.messageHandler (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:295:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:285:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:529:20)
GET / - - ms - -

/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
MongoError: Error connecting to database: server localhost:27017 timed out
    at null.<anonymous> (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:408:40)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at emit (events.js:185:7)
    at null.<anonymous> (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:144:10)
    at g (events.js:273:16)
    at emitTwo (events.js:100:13)
    at emit (events.js:185:7)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:165:12)
    at Socket.g (events.js:273:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:182:7)
    at TCP._onclose (net.js:475:12)
```

Sometimes it throws this error too:

```
/media/saket/d/git/project/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: connect EADDRNOTAVAIL 127.0.0.1:27017 - Local (127.0.0.1:0)
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
    at connect (net.js:847:16)
    at net.js:980:7
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.asyncCallback [as callback] (dns.js:63:16)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:82:10)
```